# Ubuntu Server 15.10 (Minimum Virtual Machine) Keyboard Layout

Tags: virtualbox, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using Ubuntu Server 15.10 (x86) in Virtualbox. Just want to play with it. Somehow, I just found a problem with keyboard layout. I'm using German keyboard and already set it during installation. The problem is:

(Press F4 during boot)
Ubuntu Standard Installation, after reboot keyboard remains German.
Ubuntu Minimum Installation, after reboot keyboard remains German.
Ubuntu Minimum Virtual Machine, after reboot keyboard back to US.

Probably something is not installed in Ubuntu Minimum Virtual Machine. Then I try to set it using:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

After that command, keyboard is set to German. After reboot, back to US.

But if I login to this machine using SSH, keyboard is set to German.
If I login directly from Virtualbox Window, keyboard remains US after reboot.

Probably somebody know, what package should I install to keep my keyboard in German ?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer of my own question.

Edit file **/etc/rc.local**
`sudo nano /etc/rc.local`

Now add this command before line : **exit 0**
`systemctl start console-setup`

That's all. Now reboot and keyboard stays at German.